# Do you only use rake:db:migrate:up when you only have migrations that have a up method in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, migrate

Looking through the different types of db [methods](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html) on a site and I saw that there is a `rake:db:migrate` and `rake:db:migrate:up` and `rake:db:migrate:down`. When would you use the `up` and `down` calls? Doesn't just running `rake:db:migrate` and `rake:db:rollback` do everything you need already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake db:migrate` to run all migrations under db/migrate folder

`rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20170130122612` is used to up specific migration means it runs that migration

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20170130122612` is used to down specific migration means it reverse that migration

`rake db:rollback` is used to rollback the last migration

Comment: so if you use `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20170130122612` will it also `down` all migrations that came after that version?

Comment: @mangocaptain accept & vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: For some reasons, `rake db:migrate:up` does not seem to do anything. I got no error, no feedback, no migration runned, no nothing.

Comment: Up and down of migrations are used when you have to do any changes in table. Then first you have to down the migration and then up.

Comment: @puneet18 why would you only want to run one specific migration? wouldn't you just `rails g` one migration at a time and then just run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @mangocaptain migrations are used to add/update/delete/create tables or attributes. You can create migration using `rails g` command and run it by command `rake db:migrate` but if you want to change in that migration then you have to first `down` it, then do changes in that migration file and then `up` it.

Comment: @puneet18 you can also down it and then run rake db:migrate again right? you don't have to use up because rake db:migrate will migrate all un-ran migrations?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you only use `rake db:migrate:up` when you only have migrations that have a up method in them?

No, You use

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123456789
```

when you want to run (UP) only a specific migration.

Rails automatically uses `change` method for `up` but in case of `down` it will try to reverse the migrations if possible

For example.

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer
```

becomes

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

If the reversal is not possible rails will raise `IrreversibleMigrationError`

Comment: can't you just do `rake db:migrate: VERSION=123456789` without the `up`?

Comment: @mangocaptain If you do that, it will run all migrations from `VERSION` up to the last.